# Which faction are the retail sales people part of in Divergent?

Tags: divergent

I just watched the beginning of "Divergent" with my daughter, wherein they explained all of the different factions.

I was wondering where all of the people who work in retail would fall?

It seems like I didn't hear a faction that really described them.

Comment: Let me guess: you work in retail? ;-)

Comment: Are there actual retail sales people depicted in the film? As I recall, everything one needs seems to be provided by one's faction.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Ha! Well, I'm not above it. I'm a scientist but I worked in retail for years as a student and my father does.

Comment: @recognizer Could be, I only got the chance to watch the beginning. My question originally asked if being a pure Communist society was the reason but I edited that out to avoid getting people side-trekked on that topic. Maybe that's the answer tho.

Comment: "I am a retailer, like my father before me." Sorry, first thing that came to mind.

Comment: The only example of a retail-type interaction I can think of in the films is when Tris and fellow Dauntless recruits go to Tori's tattoo parlor. However, as far as I understand it, Tori is a Dauntless providing her services to comrades free of charge.

Answer (score 1):

Like many sci-fi movie societies, *Divergent*'s faction system does not require such businesses. Since there is a faction that produces food and goods, and provides services (Abnegation), everything is covered. Any service only used by one faction is taken care of within that faction's hierarchy. There is no need for retail-like business or the creation of profit.

The idea itself could be sound in practice, assuming each faction does its job; a lot of intermediary occupations which people are overly used to today would simply be nonexistent.